# Keep main thread running while await classes haven't finished

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
  val f1: Future[Unit] = Future {
    Thread sleep 5
    println(1)
  }

  val f2: Future[Unit] = Future {
    Thread sleep 10000
    println(2)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = async {
    await(f1)
    await(f2)
 }
```

I would like the main thread to terminate after the last `await` method has terminated.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since `async/await` produces a `Future`, you need to await it as well.

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val future = async {
    await(f1)
    await(f2)
  }
  Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
}
```